# rails javascript Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am getting this error when Page fire my endless scroll on page, I use same code on 3 different pages and error triggered just on one, I cannot figure out where is error:

```
VM3507:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at DOMEval (jquery.self-06c4342….js?body=1:83)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.self-06c4342….js?body=1:347)
    at text script (jquery.self-06c4342….js?body=1:9607)
    at ajaxConvert (jquery.self-06c4342….js?body=1:8755)
    at done (jquery.self-06c4342….js?body=1:9223)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.self-06c4342….js?body=1:9515)
```

Comment: Probably an invalid javascript is loaded. Check syntax error, missing parentheses for exemple.

Comment: you'd need to show the code for this to be answerable.